# Cross product between two arrays in Scala Spark

Tags: arrays, scala, apache-spark

Consider two arrays in scala-spark

```
val mole_1 = Array(2.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
val mole_2 = Array(2.0,2.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0)
```

Now an efficient method of element-wise multiplication of the two arrays would be

```
val dot_Mole = (mole_1, mole_2).zipped.map(_ * _).sum

Which yields  >> 6.0
```

How would one use zipped and map to implement cross product between these arrays to give >> `12.0`?

USe only `zipped, map and reduce`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
val dot_mole = Mole_1.map{ x => Mole_2.map(b => b * x)}.flatten.sum
dot_mole: Double = 12.0
```